# Add fullwidth backround to TextNode that will cover any other content on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a text node to display loading text on a page if the link contains a query. I need help with adding a text node with a full-width and height white background to cover all other text on page and display a message if the link contains specific query.

Please see my code below. Thanks for the help

Javascript:

```
if (location.search === '?verify=speew') { 
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("addsigmamsg");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Please wait");

    paragraph.appendChild(text);

}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 id="addsigmamsg"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the styles mentioned above and position it at the edges of the display port (assuming there aren't any other parents with a position property) using the code below

```
if (location.search === '?verify=speew') { 
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("addsigmamsg");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Please wait");
    paragraph.appendChild(text);
    paragraph.style.position = 'absolute';
    paragraph.style.left = '0px';
    paragraph.style.top = '0px';
    paragraph.style.background = 'white';
    paragraph.style.width = '100vw'; 
    paragraph.style.height = '100vh'; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 id="addsigmamsg"></h1>
```